# cakePHP application install

Tags: cakephp

H!

I'm new to cakePHP I have have a cakePHP application . I got from
https://github.com/OldWest/CakePHP-1.3-MEIO-image-upload-sample-code

I want to install this in my wamp server. PHP version:5.4.16

I am getting 3 errors
1.Warning: include(cake\bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\cake\webroot\index.php on line 76

2.Warning: include(): Failed opening 'cake\bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='E:\wamp\www_cake\cakephp-cakephp-1.3.2-38-g8581350\cakephp-cakephp-8581350;D:\wamp\www\cake\;.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp\www\cake\webroot\index.php on line 76

3.Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors root directory. in D:\wamp\www\cake\webroot\index.php on line 77

How Can i use the same cakePHP folder used for Blog application in tutorials
I mean multiple application with same cakePHP library How?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use version 1.3. it is an old version.
Use the latest. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/2.4.6

The old versions will get you in trouble (as a beginner) with new php versions.

Also, the framework had evolved greatly since 1.3.

Comment: If he has existing application then? He can't do so.

Comment: @IsaacRajaei Have you read the question at all?! he is a beginner who tries to work with the tutorial..

Comment: doesn't matter. many beginners are working on many existing frameworks. The answer should be a general answer and helpful for the next developer not what you prefer my friend.

Comment: But it does. the answer should address the question and help productivity. yours is good for neither.

Answer (score 0):

Not new to either php or programming here, but I too am saddled with a cake 1.3 site that must be yanked along to work with newer code.  Telling people to just upgrade is not helpful.

I looked in the 'advanced configuration' section here https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation.html
and by examining the current index.php found that my existing installation was expecting the core cake files to be elsewhere entirely on the system.  You could then either plunk the core files where expected, or change the configuration in index.php, depending on current practices.